# How to avoid the same file showing up repeatedly in Advanced Drive Services Change List

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to check for items deleted in the a Shared Drive using the Drive API via Advanced Services. However, I keep seeing the same deleted files over and over again every time I run the script.

I'm setting a new startPageToken after each run, saving it as a script property, and fetching it for the next run, so that's not the issue. Also in the same script I'm successfully checking for edits in the same Shared Drive and I see that the list of edits updates when files are edited, so I know I am getting the latest revisions list. But somehow those same deleted files keep showing up.

My one theory on this is that the deleted files are still open on someone's computer and somehow reloading frequently, causing Google Drive to log a view for them, and hence counting them as changed. I know from working with the edited files that views do cause files to appear in the change list even if they haven't changed. I can get around this with viewed files by checking the modifiedDate to see if the file has actually been modified since the last script run, but with the deleted files I can't figure out how to determine the deletion date or anything else that might help me filter out false positives.

I need a way to differentiate between files that have actually been deleted since the script last ran and these weird ghost files. The obvious answer would be to find a way to determine when the file was actually deleted, but I'm not sure how to do that. modifiedDate is not updated when files are deleted, and since I'm trying to do this all within GAS as a container bound script using advanced services, I only have access to Drive API v2 so haven't been able to figure out how to get the deleted date for a file.

Here's the simplified version of the function used to get the change list:

```
function watchDrive() {
  const id = "[SHARED DRIVE ID GOES HERE]";
  const driveName = "TEST";

  // Script properties to store page tokens
  let scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  // Set fields to fetch. Note that deleting user and timestamp are not available in Drive API v2
  const fields =
      "newStartPageToken,"
      +"items("
        +"file("
          +"id,"
          +"title,"
          +"labels(trashed),"
          +"iconLink,"
          +"mimeType,"
          +"createdDate,"
          +"ownedByMe,"
          +"modifiedDate,"
          +"lastModifyingUser("
            +"emailAddress,"
            +"displayName,"
            +"picture(url)"
          +"),"
          +"alternateLink,"
          +"fileSize"
        +")"
      +")";


  try {
    // Get existing token if it exists, or create new one
    const pageToken =
      scriptProperties.getProperty(id) 
      || Drive.Changes.getStartPageToken({ driveId: id, supportsAllDrives: true    }).startPageToken;

    // Get drive changes list and corresponding newStartPageToken to use on next script run
    const { newStartPageToken, items = [] } = Drive.Changes.list({
      fields,
      pageToken,
      driveId: id,
      includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
      includeRemoved: true,
      pageSize: 1000,
      supportsAllDrives: true
    });

    // Save new page token for next script run
    if (newStartPageToken) {
      scriptProperties.setProperty(id, newStartPageToken);
    }

    // If changed/deleted items found, process the list to prep it for email and split into separate arrays for changes and deletions
    if (items.length) {
      let deletedItems = getDeleted_(items);
      Logger.log(deletedItems);

    } else {
      Logger.log(`No changes found in ${driveName}`);
    }
  } catch(error) {
    Logger.log("ERROR: " + error);
  }
}
```

And here's the function it calls to filter by deleted files:

```
function getDeleted_(items) {

  let deleted = items
    .map(({ file }) => file)
    .filter(({ id, alternateLink, title }) => id && alternateLink && title)
    .filter(({ labels: { trashed = null } = {} }) => trashed === true);

  return deleted;
}
```

Note that this code was adapted from the example found here: https://www.labnol.org/google-drive-monitor-201026

Comment: Hi @HannahS., was the answer below able to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the difference between the accumulated deleted ids of previous runs vs the current deleted ids of current run then filter your `deletedItems` using those IDs. See code below.

#### Code:

```
if (items.length) {
  let deletedItems = getDeleted_(items);
  // get IDs of previous run of deletedItems, blank if not initialized
  let prevDeletedIds = scriptProperties.getProperty("deletedIds") || "";
  // get unique Ids of prevDeletedIds (in case of duplicates)
  prevDeletedIds = prevDeletedIds.split(",").filter(onlyUnique);

  // get unique IDs of deletedItems (in case of duplicates)
  let deletedIds = deletedItems.map(item => item.id).filter(onlyUnique);
  // get ids from deletedIds not present in prevDeletedIds
  let differenceIds = deletedIds.filter(item => !prevDeletedIds.includes(item));

  // only include items found in differenceIds
  deletedItems = deletedItems.filter(item => differenceIds.includes(item.id));

  // set accumulated deletedIds (including prevDeletedIds) as deletedIds
  scriptProperties.setProperty("deletedIds", deletedIds.join(",").concat("," + prevDeletedIds.join(",")));
  Logger.log(deletedItems);
}

// function for filtering unique values of array
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

#### Steps:

- Store the accumulated unique ids of all the runs before (e.g. `id1`, `id2`)
- In the next run, get the `deletedItems` unique ids stored in a variable (e.g. `id1`, `id2`, `id3`, assuming it contains all the ids deleted including from the previous runs based on your issue)
- Get the difference between the current unique ids vs the one in the property.
- Filter your `deletedItems` based on the ids you got as difference (`id3`) from the previous step.
- Store all accumulated deleted ids you got (`id1`, `id2`, `id3`) in the property again, log `deletedItems` and end the script.